# Decoding Is Not Supported ("DocumentID values can only be decoded with Firestore.Decoder")

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following `struct`:

```swift
struct Recipe: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var vegetarian: Bool?
}
```

And this is how I'm parsing the data from Firestore:

```swift
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let recipeToDisplay = try decoder.decode(Recipe.self, from: data!)
                    
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
                    
    FirestoreService.createRecipe(
        documentId: uuid,
        vegetarian: recipeToDisplay.vegetarian ?? false
    ) { recipeURL in
        print("success")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error parsing response data: \(error)")
}
```

The `catch` statement is getting called and I'm getting the following error message: `decodingIsNotSupported("DocumentID values can only be decoded with Firestore.Decoder")`.

All the documentation I've researched has pointed me towards using `JSONDecoder()` to parse the data and I can't find anything on `Firestore.Decoder`. Is there a different way that I should be parsing the data?

Comment: See the Recipe example using the Firestore Decoder in https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/firestore

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks for the link! Although I'm not able to find any Recipe example anywhere in the repository. Do you know where I should be looking?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's Restaurant not Recipe in the example https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/firestore/FirestoreExample/Restaurant.swift#L20 - it should still be a good template for you.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that I was trying to decode `id` from a source that didn't have an `id` property. Excluding `id` from my `CodingKeys` resolved the issue.

```
struct Recipe: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var vegetarian: Bool?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case vegetarian
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't using an explicit Codable implementation. Unfortunately you have to add in all that nonsense boiler plate in order for it to work. Rather than use the default.

So go ahead and bloat your model with:

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey

init(from decoder: Decoder)

func encode(to encoder: Encoder)